# Pushbullet: No notifications in official Chrome extension when pushing via API

Tags: pushbullet

The official Chrome extension isn't behaving as I'd expect (and is not what how it behaved before).  I've uninstalled and reinstalled it from Chrome store before doing this.

Using the randomchars pushbullet python client (https://github.com/randomchars/pushbullet.py):

```
from pushbullet import PushBullet
$key=...
pb=PushBullet($key)
s,p=pb.push_note("title","body")
```

The above note should be pushed to all devices.  But while it appears on the official android app, it does not appear on the official Chrome extension.

However, the following works and is displayed on the Chrome extension:

```
c=pb.devices[0]   # Chrome client
s,p=c.push_note("title","body")
```

Tried a variant using curl. This push is displayed on the official Android client, but not the official Chrome extension:

```
curl -u "${key}:" -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes --data-binary '{"type": "note", "title": "Note Title", "body": "Note Title"}'
```

But acting on a hunch after comparing the differences in metadata between displayed pushes and non-displayed notifications, I added a "source_device_iden" tag (matching my Android client), and this was displayed on the offical Chrome extension:

```
curl -u "${key}:" -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes --data-binary '{"type": "note", "title": "Note Title", "body": "Note Title", "source_device_iden": "uSOMETHING"}'
```

Does the Chrome extension now require either source_device_iden or dest_device_iden to be populated or something?

Comment: does not appear to be about programming chrome extensions. seems like a support issue to the developer of that ext.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I have removed the incorrect tag.

Comment: Well, it magically works now. Not sure if there was a stealthy backend patch, but it works now.  I'll leave this question here unless someone tells me I should delete it instead.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug that we fixed yesterday.  Thanks for letting us know!